# Change button on clicked and records update in database and vice versa

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I have one button called as delete. If any user clicked on delete then delete text will replace by restore and delete action will perform in the database.
Same think I have to set on the restore button. If clicked on restore then replace text by delete and restore action will perform but I need only one button.
Please check my below code. There is delete button and when I clicked on delete button it is displaying restore button and redirecting to perform the delete event.

I know how to delete and restore the records in php. I need script to perform.
Change button I did with the help of Jquery. Without refreshing, I have to display restore button.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.btn").click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('btn')) {
            $(this).html('Restore').toggleClass('btn');
        } else {
            $(this).html('Delete').toggleClass('btn');
        }
    });
});


function b_delete(id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "process.php?function=b_delete&record_id=id",
        data: {
            record_id:record_id
        },
        success: function (data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        }
    });
    
    return false;
}
```

```css
a{
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-center
{
text-align: center;
}
.btn{
 background-color: blue;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 10px 15px;

}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-center">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return b_delete('<?php echo $user_Id;?>')"  class="btn">Delete</a>
</div>
```

**Process.php**

```
switch($_GET['function']) {
case 'b_delete':b_delete($conn);break;
default : redirect('index.php');
}

function b_delete($conn)
{
$record_id=$_GET['record_id'];
echo "testing";
}
```

Comment: when clicking on the button, send an Ajax request to your php script where you delete/restore things in db. this is the only way without refreshing the page

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Cashbee. I agree with you but how can we access that

Comment: Mr.Cashbee, I tried like <a onClick="javascript:onclickFunction('id')" href="process.php?record_id=<?php echo $user_Id;?>" class="btn">Delete</a>

Comment: Hey Mr.Cashbee, I tried using ajax but still issue. Can you help me

Comment: checkout firebase, it makes doing things like this really simple https://firebase.google.com/

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Alan, It is not related to my question.Can more help?

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt at ajax is not so bad, but i could see some minor things that i changed in the following code:

**Html**

```
<div class="btn-center">
    <button id="delete_restore" onclick="b_delete(this, '<?php echo $user_Id;?>')" class="btn">Delete</a>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function b_delete(element, user_id){

    // change text of button
    if (element.hasClass('btn')) {
        element.html('Restore').toggleClass('btn');
    } else {
        element.html('Delete').toggleClass('btn');
    }


    /* where is this coming from? */
    var record_id = 9999;


    var mode = 'b_delete';
    if(!element.hasClass('btn')){
        mode = 'b_restore';
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "process.php",
        data: {
            user_id: user_id,
            mode: mode,
            record_id: record_id
        },
        success: function (data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            console.log("ajax request failed", xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

**process.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['mode'])){
    switch($_POST['mode']) {
        case 'b_delete': b_delete($conn);break;
        case 'b_restore': b_restore($conn);break;
        default : header('Location: index.php'); //maybe use full url, i dont know for sure
    }
}

function b_delete($conn)
{
    $record_id=$_POST['record_id'];
    echo "testing delete";
}
function b_restore($conn)
{
    $record_id=$_POST['record_id'];
    echo "testing restore";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Cashbee. I tried your code and when  I clicked on delete button, No action performed.

Comment: edited my code (de-commented declaration of the var record_id).
 you have to look in your developer-tools console for any messages. If the code works, it will output the testing strings there, if it doesnt there will be some sort of errors there

Comment: Mr.Cashee, I am getting error SyntaxError: unterminated string literal  

b_delete(this, '<br /> in console

Answer (score 0):

You can try assigning a data attribute to `a`.

```
<a data-action="delete">Delete</a>
```

Then in your script:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
   if ($(this).data('action') == 'delete')
   {
     //Do your ajax for delete
     $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "process.php?function=b_delete",
        data: {
            'record_id':record_id
        },
        success: function (data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        }
     });

     $(this).text('Restore');
     $(this).data('action', 'restore');
   } else {
     //Do  your ajax for restore
     $(this).text('Delete');
     $(this).data('action', 'delete');
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.herondale, Can you share the ajax code because I am confused now. How to call ajax from here?

Comment: @NarendraVerma Just copy then paste your ajax request code from your function `b_delete()` in the statement for delete in the click event handler, you can do that before the `$(this).text('Restore');` where I put the comment. Do the same for restore.

Comment: Still same issue Mr.herondale, No action performed after clicked on delete.

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: hmm, i just noticed there is a bit of redundancy here. try removing `&record_id=id` from the url and see if that works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135924/discussion-between-narendra-verma-and-herondale).

Answer (score 0):

You are using get method for ajax call,
you can either pass parameters through url or using data.
There is a small error while passing value of parameter "record_id" in data.
It must be data:{record_id:id}

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->
<style>
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.btn {
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
</style>
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-center">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);"
        onclick="return b_delete('<?php echo $user_id;?>')" class="btn">Delete</a>
</div>

<!-- end snippet -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a.btn").click(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('btn')) {
                $(this).html('Restore').toggleClass('btn');
            } else {
                $(this).html('Delete').toggleClass('btn');
            }
        });
    });


    function b_delete(id){
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "process.php?function=b_delete&record_id=id",
            data: {
                record_id:id
            },
            success: function (data){
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Saurabh, it is working but after refresh, it become   restore button is replaced by delete

Comment: When page refreshes, you will have to check for status of the required record_id from database. if 'Status' states record is deleted we have to display "Restore" button or else "Delete".

Comment: Right. but where should I add that code? Can you help me with code please?